# Visual Studio Android App doesn't open Main.axml

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have just downloaded Xamarin for Visual Studio (2015) and created a new "Blank App (Android)" project.

When I try to open Main.axml file in the solution, it is loading for around a minute and then I get this error:

[image]

I found some related topics online, and all of them suggested updating Android SDK tools to version 24.3 or later.

I have checked the Android SDK Manager and I have version 25.1.

The error details don't make any sense to me, but I assume it has something to do with java?

Any Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace for this error

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have JDK 1.8(x64) installed. Secondly ensure that it is the current JDK set in your Xamarin options.

If you have older JDKs installed, I would advise to remove previous JDKs like 1.7 via Control Panel.

**Note:** The x64 bits are needed for custom control support via:

> Additionally, a 64-bit version of the JDK is required to use [custom controls in the Android designer](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#androiddesignercustomcontrols).
>
> The simplest option is to install the 64-bit version of JDK 1.8 since it is backwards compatible with all of the previous API levels and supports the new Android designer features.

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/